# latexdiff in linuxmint Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex;

Tags: linux, latexdiff

I have linuxmint OS, am a relatively new linux user, and I have found that multiple people have had this problem with latexdiff but I cannot figure out how to solve this and have spent a lot of time on it.  I am under the impression after reading a few posts that this problem has been solved in the new latexdiff version, but I do not understand how to install that and cannot find clear instructions for my system. I have tried sudo apt-get install latexdiff, but it says latexdiff is already the newest version (1.1.1-1).

```
    $ latexdiff --v
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/\\includeonly{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 1572.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/(^(?:[^%\n]|\\%)*)\\bibliography{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 1607.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/(^(?:[^%\n]|\\%)*)\\subfile{ <-- HERE (.*?)}/ at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 1622.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/(?<!\\)\\{ <-- HERE / at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 2351.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/\\begin{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}((?:(.(?!(?<!\\)\&|\\\\))*)?)\\end{MATHMODE}/ at   /usr/bin/latexdiff line 2676.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/\\begin{MATHMODE}((?:(.(?!(?<!\\)\&|\\\\))*)?)\\end{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}/ at   /usr/bin/latexdiff line 2676.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/\\begin{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}(.*?)\\end{MATHMODE}/ at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 2678.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/\\begin{MATHMODE}(.*?)\\end{ <-- HERE MATHMODE}/ at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 2678.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/\\end{ <-- HERE SQUAREBRACKET}/ at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 2759.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in     m/\\begin{ <-- HERE SQUAREBRACKET}/ at /usr/bin/latexdiff line 2760.
Option v is ambiguous (verbose, version, visible-label)
2 and only 2 non-option arguments required.  Write latexdiff -h to get help
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I've got latexdiff 1.2.1 and this does not issue any warnings. Do you use vanilla TeX Live or the distro package?

Comment: Until Debian/LinuxMint TeX Live is updated, you just have to live with the warning. Or, if you’re braver, install TeX Live yourself, which would guarantee faster updates.

Comment: Related: [List of Perl scripts that have fixed the unescaped literal character problem](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7464)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I have seen that post, but I still do not understand how to solve the problem.  Can I install just that updated package from github? How do I do this?

Comment: @egreg I would live with the warning, but the problem is latexdiff will not produce a pdf file for me.  I was thinking this was the problem , because both tex files compile separately, but will not produce a  diff.tex file when run through latexdiff.

Comment: @teXnician I use the distro package, but it looks like I would have to install tex live myself to get the version you have. I will research how to do that but it seems a lot of work (especially with me being a relatively new linux user) to just get the 1 package latexdiff

Comment: You can also just download the newer version of `latexdiff` from ctan and run that (it's a perl script in a single file).

Comment: @marijn I have downloaded that, but can  you be more specific about what to do?  I have tried running it, from the folder I have downloaded it from, but am getting the same error message.  This makes me think I have not run the same version I have download, but am still running the old verison

Comment: You can check which version you are running with `latexdiff --version`. In Linux you have to specify that you want to run the script from the current directory with `./latexdiff`, otherwise the system default will be run.

Comment: @marijin Thanks, I have tried both of those things just after I downloaded the new version.  However when I type latexdiff --version in the terminal, it does not give the version, but the error typed in the question.  When I type ./latexdiff in the directory I newly downloaded it gives the error: $ ./latexdiff
Can't locate Algorithm/Diff.pm in... (you may need to install the Algorithm::Diff module) (... contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl...

Comment: Are there any other programs besides latexdiff that do similar?  I am trying to track changes for a paper submission

Comment: @pwprnt  In the question you typed in `latexdiff --v` instead of `latexdiff --version`. Try the latter.  There are versions of latexdiff not depending on Algorithm/Diff.pm . If you download from CTAN these are included already (latexdiff-so or latexdiff-fast). If you downloaded from github you have to use the Makefile to construct them.

Comment: I have also tried latexdiff --version and it give the same error. I have downloaded from CTAN, but it seems I am not able to run the program from the folder i have put it in.  I must be doing something wrong, but what I have done is downloaded the zipped file from CTAN, unzipped it, changed to the folder where latexdiff program is located, and then typed ./latexdiff.  This gives that error result in the previous comment (Can't locate Algorithm/Diff.pm in...) as well.

Comment: @frederik in addition to the comment I just posted, I have now run:  $ ./latexdiff-fast old.tex new.tex > diff.tex , but this will not produce a pdf file, becuase of the unescaped literal character problem